# Error when Using multiple classes with taking inputs all at once

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

If I use just one class it works perfect but when I am using multiple classes, I am facing an issue ,where ,When I am giving the input as whole as a batch (copy paste) it doesn't work (still waits for some more input and does nothing), but when I give each input manually it works perfect.

So , this problem started when I introduced a new class so I guess there is something wrong with the class or inheritance when utilizing with the Scanner class .

Kindly compare and let me know the mistakes

Note : this is for my college elab , so I cant use files over here.

btw , MyInputs are

5

5 0

2 9 -10 25 1

5 1

2 9 -10 25 1

5 1

2 9 -10 25 1

5 0

2 9 -10 25 1

5 1

2 9 -10 25 1

expected Output

5.400000

4.000000

4.000000

5.400000

4.000000

codeWithSingleClass -Works perfect

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    int nooftestCases=scanner.nextInt();

    while(nooftestCases>0) {
        int n,k;
        int[] array = new int[20];
        int sumWithOutRemoval=0 , sumWithRemoval=0;
        n = scanner.nextInt();
        k = scanner.nextInt();
        sumWithOutRemoval = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            sumWithOutRemoval += array[i];
        }
        if (k == 0) {
            double finalAns = (double) sumWithOutRemoval / n;
            System.out.println(String.format("%.6f", finalAns));
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
                    if (array[i] < array[j]) {
                        int temp = array[i];
                        array[i] = array[j];
                        array[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            sumWithRemoval = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
                sumWithRemoval += array[i];
            }
            double finalAns = (double) (sumWithRemoval / (n - (2 * k)));
            System.out.println(String.format("%.6f", finalAns));
        }
        nooftestCases--;
    }
  }
 }



--->codeWithMultipleClasses-hasIssues<----

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Sample {

 static int n,k;
 static int[] array = new int[20];
 static int sumWithOutRemoval , sumWithRemoval;

 public void getDetails(){
    Scanner scanner2=new Scanner(System.in);
    n = scanner2.nextInt();
    k = scanner2.nextInt();
    sumWithOutRemoval = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        array[i] = scanner2.nextInt();
        sumWithOutRemoval += array[i];
    }
  }
 public void displayDetails(){
    if (k == 0) {
        double finalAns = (double) sumWithOutRemoval / n;
        System.out.println(String.format("%.6f", finalAns));
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
                if (array[i] < array[j]) {
                    int temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        sumWithRemoval = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
            sumWithRemoval += array[i];
        }
        double finalAns = (double) (sumWithRemoval / (n - (2 * k)));
        System.out.println(String.format("%.6f", finalAns));
    }
 }
 }
 public class Main extends Sample {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    int nooftestCases=scanner.nextInt();
    Sample objname= new Sample();
    while(nooftestCases>0) {
        objname.getDetails();
        objname.displayDetails();
        nooftestCases--;
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: So you are copy pasting the input separated by whitespaces?

Comment: @JimS Yes , I am

Comment: Do you hit enter when you type? Copy/Paste may not include newlinr.

Comment: @Deadpool I have given the input now , kindly check

Comment: The scanner moves to the next input when a newline character is typed (when you press enter). If you want to enter them all at once try separating them by newlines.

Comment: but still how are you expecting this should work by copy pasting input at a time @RitteshP.V

Comment: @JimS well , the inputs is automatically inserted as whole in college elab website , anyway please let me know the alternatives

Comment: @Deadpool where could be the mistakes and how do I solve this ? Kindly help me

Comment: @RitteshP.V well we need to know the format they are inserted in so we can parse them accordingly. Are they inserted separated by whitespace between each input?

Comment: @BaileyKocin but that's how I gotta make it work , since it's for my college elab and they have a option where inputs are copied all once in that compiler.

Comment: @JimS yes they are inserted by whitespace seperated

Comment: I feel your pain! College labs are sometimes not the best. Perhaps I do not completely know what's going on but can you ask the instructor about it?  I bet it would be educational.

Comment: @BaileyKocin yea , okay i'll asking him

Comment: The problem is you are feeding everything before it asks? so in that case you need to code in that way @RitteshP.V, still you can make this two cases work, but it will be huge logic change, so i will say try to understand the requirement completely

Comment: @Deadpool there is the other way I thought of doing it by using structures and take with the inputs all at once and then work it , but I know it's a hectic work to do.

Comment: If you want to do that way, you can but after making changes current way will not work, mostly you have to choose either of this @RitteshP.V

Comment: Guys , sorry ,  I forgot to mention one important thing this program works fine when I use just one class . Irrespective of the input method. So this issue was arrived only when I moved to the multi class concept.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you have an input given like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

And then you press enter when you are done.
If that's the case then you need to parse the input as a string and split it into the arguments:

```
   public static void main(String[] args){
       Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
       String input = scanner.nextLine();
       String[] arguments = input.split("[ \n]");
       System.out.println("First argument:"+arguments[0]);
       System.out.println("Last argument:"+arguments[arguments.length - 1]);
       //do something with the arguments
   }
```